# Android device administration

Tags: android, device-admin

I am trying to develop an app with the help of device administration policies to disable stock camera on non-rooted devices,and the key point will be that the policy can't be deactivated by anyone without entering password

can you someone please tell me the possibility of the above scenario..If yes, please share any tutorial links for it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "entering password" ? Screen lock?

Comment: not screen lock but preventing access to disable the policy by the user...user must not be able to do it whereas admin should be able to do it...

Comment: Are you developing only an app or entire Android source code ?

Comment: developing only an app